# cannot invoke 'stringFromDate' error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to do a simple date format in **Swift** but I'm getting the following error:

```
"Cannot invoke 'stringFromDate' with an argument list of type '(NSDate?!)'"
```

My code is as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 

    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", 

    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = ("dd-MMM-yyyy")

    var myUsers: AnyObject = users[indexPath.row]

    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myUsers.createdAt)


    return cell
}
```

}

Does anyone know why I can't do this in **Swift**? I have used this method before and it worked fine. I have searched other answers but I haven't found anything suitable.

Appreciate any help available. Many thanks

Comment: don't you have to convert `myUsers` to a user object first ? Right now it's `AnyObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the following code:

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let d = NSDate()
    let s = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)
    println(s)
```

Comment: You are correct but this OP does not understand it. He/she just copied and pasted without understanding it.

Answer (score -1):

**This is for your first post:**

This line of code is not set up the format properly because this is called for converting from `String` to `Date`:

```
dateFormatter.dateFromString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

So, you have to set up the format first like this, it's just a minor error and be careful next time:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

---

**This is for the post after you edited:**

There has an obvious error here:

```
var myUsers: AnyObject = users[indexPath.row]
```

`AnyObject` does not have property `createdAt`. That's why you can not get it right. And make sure that `users` array is an array of 'PFUser'. Otherwise, it will still have errors.

Comment: If OP changed this code, it still wouldn’t work. the `stringFromDate“…”)` should be used to input the string that needs to be converted to the date. the dateFormat is (indeed) used to set the format, but you still need to use `stringFromDate`

Comment: For my understand, `myUsers.createdAt` is an instance of `Date`. First of all, format has to be set and I am correct at this point. And purpose of this is to convert from `Date` to `String`. So, why do you need `dateFromString`. I do not see the purpose of converting from `String` to `Date`. @milo526